# database export to excel file using codeigniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

Here I show some partial code for database table export my excel file. The file is written but not right formatted:

```
function get_report(){
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $query = $this->pharmacy_model->get_report();
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, ';');
    force_download('CSV_Report.csv', $data);
}
```

It is downloaded and extracted with data, but format is not right. I need it like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu4tP.jpg)

Comment: check this link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2016/05/how-to-export-to-excel-in-codeigniter-3.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, ';');
```

just use `','` instead of *semi-colon* () in this

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Get MySql data in key value pair.**

```
    Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Parvez Alam
            [Age] => 21
            [Gender] => Male
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Shavez Alam
            [Age] => 21
            [Gender] => Male
        )

)
```

**Step 2: PHP code to get options type and force to browser download file instead of display.**

```
if(isset($_POST["ExportType"]))
```

{

```
switch($_POST["ExportType"])
{
    case "export-to-excel" :
        // Submission from
        $filename = $_POST["ExportType"] . ".xls";       
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        ExportFile($data);
        //$_POST["ExportType"] = '';
        exit();
    default :
        die("Unknown action : ".$_POST["action"]);
        break;
}
```

}

```
function ExportFile($records) {
    $heading = false;
        if(!empty($records))
          foreach($records as $row) {
            if(!$heading) {
              // display field/column names as a first row
              echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
              $heading = true;
            }
            echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
          }
        exit;
}
```

**Step 3: Define html layout for display data in table and button to fire export-to-csv action.**

```
<div><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="export-to-excel">Export to excel</a></div>


<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" id="export-form">
                        <input type="hidden" value='' id='hidden-type' name='ExportType'/>
                      </form>
                  <table id="" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Priority</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                  </tr>
                <tbody>
                  <?php foreach($data as $row):?>
                  <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row ['Name']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row ['Status']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row ['Priority']?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row ['Salary']?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

**Step 4: Now we will use jQuery code to get click event.**

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#Export to excel').bind("click", function() {
var target = $(this).attr('id');
switch(target) {
    case 'export-to-excel' :
    $('#hidden-type').val(target);
    //alert($('#hidden-type').val());
    $('#export-form').submit();
    $('#hidden-type').val('');
    break
}
});
    });
</script>
```